# Gmail refuses to open

Tags: gmail, google-account

Since a few days, my Gmail account is opening very slowly, or refuses to open for a very long time. I checked and this is not a wi-fi or internet connection problem.

What can I do to make it open?

Comment: ctrl+shift+del and delete cookies